# When is a web page or project considered complete?

Tags: asp.net, html

I have been asked to design a website for a client as a "side job". I am trying to write up a statement of work for the project. In the past, I have done similar work, and often run into a situation where I believe the work is "done", but the client wants endless tweaks and changes. (As you know, websites are perpetually "under construction").

When you have requirements such as "Design a Home page, design a Contact Us page" how you define a page as "done"?

Comment: Software is like poetry: you never finish, you just run out of time.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put anything live, until they accept your work is complete. This should be enough of an incentive for them not to string you along, and allows them to have the quality website they require.

Answer (score 0):

Ask the client to set up a requirements specification for version 1. When you met the requirements contained in this document is your job completed. Everything else belongs to the next version.

Answer (score 0):

In the same situations, I tell my client **"you want A, B, C and D. OK, sign here, and we are agreed that the end of application is A-D. Now if you wanted something more in future, it is not a part of our contract, so we'll deal with that in future and of course it has it's own price."** This way you make them think before signing and lot's of things become clearer, and lots of needs show up suddenly, but in future they'll either pay more for more needs or won't talk any more :)